# Togl_SwapBuffers flushes whole screen and not only the window, I wanted to draw into

Tags: c, user-interface, opengl, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a C-Programm running under Ubuntu and have tried to make it work under Windows. The Programm uses Tcl/Tk, ToGL and OpenGL to draw plots into several Windows on the screen.

That's why I have installed Tcl/Tk 8.6.3 and ToGL 2.0 on my Windows 7 and tried to compile the programme in Visual Studio 2013 (including opengl32 lib and dll from existing System directories on my PC).

Everything went fine, but when I wanted to draw a plot, my whole Screen turned black (which is also the background color of the plot) with the plot in the left down edge. Then I checked a sample file from the Internet (which I appended here) to check, whether it is my fault or some Problem with the library and the same Problem occured).

I have located the problem as far, as the screen is flushed immediatelly after Togl_SwapBuffers, but cannot find out, what I have to Change, to fix the Problem. The Problem occurs on several (all I've checked) Windows PCs.

```
    #define USE_TOGL_STUBS

    #include "togl.h"
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #undef TCL_STORAGE_CLASS
    #define TCL_STORAGE_CLASS DLLEXPORT

    #ifndef M_PI
    #  define M_PI 3.14159265
    #endif
    #define FM_PI ((float) M_PI)

    #ifdef _MSC_VER


    #endif

    struct WHIRLYGIZMO
    {
        int     Gear1, Gear2, Gear3;
        double  Rotx, Roty, Rotz;
        double  Angle;
        int     Height, Width;
    };

    typedef struct WHIRLYGIZMO WHIRLYGIZMO;


    static void
    gear(GLfloat inner_radius, GLfloat outer_radius, GLfloat width,
            GLint teeth, GLfloat tooth_depth)
    {
        GLint   i;
        GLfloat r0, r1, r2;
        GLfloat angle, da;
        GLfloat u, v, len;

        r0 = inner_radius;
        r1 = outer_radius - tooth_depth / 2;
        r2 = outer_radius + tooth_depth / 2;

        da = 2 * FM_PI / teeth / 4;

        glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);

        glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);

        /* draw front face */
        glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
        for (i = 0; i <= teeth; i++) {
            angle = i * 2 * FM_PI / teeth;
            glVertex3f(r0 * cos(angle), r0 * sin(angle), width * 0.5f);
            glVertex3f(r1 * cos(angle), r1 * sin(angle), width * 0.5f);
            glVertex3f(r0 * cos(angle), r0 * sin(angle), width * 0.5f);
            glVertex3f(r1 * cos(angle + 3 * da), r1 * sin(angle + 3 * da),
                    width * 0.5f);
        }
        glEnd();

        /* draw front sides of teeth */
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        da = 2 * FM_PI / teeth / 4;
        for (i = 0; i < teeth; i++) {
            angle = i * 2 * FM_PI / teeth;

            glVertex3f(r1 * cos(angle), r1 * sin(angle), width * 0.5f);
            glVertex3f(r2 * cos(angle + da), r2 * sin(angle + da), width * 0.5f);
            glVertex3f(r2 * cos(angle + 2 * da), r2 * sin(angle + 2 * da),
                    width * 0.5f);
            glVertex3f(r1 * cos(angle + 3 * da), r1 * sin(angle + 3 * da),
                    width * 0.5f);
        }
        glEnd();


        glNormal3f(0, 0, -1);

        /* draw back face */
        glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
        for (i = 0; i <= teeth; i++) {
            angle = i * 2 * FM_PI / teeth;
            glVertex3f(r1 * cos(angle), r1 * sin(angle), -width * 0.5f);
            glVertex3f(r0 * cos(angle), r0 * sin(angle), -width * 0.5f);
            glVertex3f(r1 * cos(angle + 3 * da), r1 * sin(angle + 3 * da),
                    -width * 0.5f);
            glVertex3f(r0 * cos(angle), r0 * sin(angle), -width * 0.5f);
        }
        glEnd();

        /* draw back sides of teeth */
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        da = 2 * FM_PI / teeth / 4;
        for (i = 0; i < teeth; i++) {
            angle = i * 2 * FM_PI / teeth;

            glVertex3f(r1 * cos(angle + 3 * da), r1 * sin(angle + 3 * da),
                    -width * 0.5f);
            glVertex3f(r2 * cos(angle + 2 * da), r2 * sin(angle + 2 * da),
                    -width * 0.5f);
            glVertex3f(r2 * cos(angle + da), r2 * sin(angle + da), -width * 0.5f);
            glVertex3f(r1 * cos(angle), r1 * sin(angle), -width * 0.5f);
        }
        glEnd();


        /* draw outward faces of teeth */
        glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
        for (i = 0; i < teeth; i++) {
            angle = i * 2 * FM_PI / teeth;

            glVertex3f(r1 * cos(angle), r1 * sin(angle), width * 0.5f);
            glVertex3f(r1 * cos(angle), r1 * sin(angle), -width * 0.5f);
            u = r2 * cos(angle + da) - r1 * cos(angle);
            v = r2 * sin(angle + da) - r1 * sin(angle);
            len = sqrt(u * u + v * v);
            u /= len;
            v /= len;
            glNormal3f(v, -u, 0);
            glVertex3f(r2 * cos(angle + da), r2 * sin(angle + da), width * 0.5f);
            glVertex3f(r2 * cos(angle + da), r2 * sin(angle + da), -width * 0.5f);
            glNormal3f(cos(angle), sin(angle), 0);
            glVertex3f(r2 * cos(angle + 2 * da), r2 * sin(angle + 2 * da),
                    width * 0.5f);
            glVertex3f(r2 * cos(angle + 2 * da), r2 * sin(angle + 2 * da),
                    -width * 0.5f);
            u = r1 * cos(angle + 3 * da) - r2 * cos(angle + 2 * da);
            v = r1 * sin(angle + 3 * da) - r2 * sin(angle + 2 * da);
            glNormal3f(v, -u, 0);
            glVertex3f(r1 * cos(angle + 3 * da), r1 * sin(angle + 3 * da),
                    width * 0.5f);
            glVertex3f(r1 * cos(angle + 3 * da), r1 * sin(angle + 3 * da),
                    -width * 0.5f);
            glNormal3f(cos(angle), sin(angle), 0);
        }

        glVertex3f(r1 /* * cos(0) */, /* r1 * sin(0) */ 0, width * 0.5f);
        glVertex3f(r1 /* * cos(0) */, /* r1 * sin(0) */ 0, -width * 0.5f);

        glEnd();


        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

        /* draw inside radius cylinder */
        glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
        for (i = 0; i <= teeth; i++) {
            angle = i * 2 * FM_PI / teeth;
            glNormal3f(-cos(angle), -sin(angle), 0);
            glVertex3f(r0 * cos(angle), r0 * sin(angle), -width * 0.5f);
            glVertex3f(r0 * cos(angle), r0 * sin(angle), width * 0.5f);
        }
        glEnd();

    }


    static int counter;

    static int
    draw(ClientData clientData, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj *const *objv)
    {

        WHIRLYGIZMO *Wg;
        Togl   *togl;
        if(counter++ % (1000)) return TCL_OK;
        if (objc != 2) {
            Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 1, objv, "pathName");
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }

        if (Togl_GetToglFromObj(interp, objv[1], &togl) != TCL_OK) {
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        Wg = (WHIRLYGIZMO *) Togl_GetClientData(togl);
        //glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef((float) Wg->Rotx, 1, 0, 0);
        glRotatef((float) Wg->Roty, 0, 1, 0);
        glRotatef((float) Wg->Rotz, 0, 0, 1);

        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-3, -2, 0);
        glRotatef((float) Wg->Angle, 0, 0, 1);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glCallList(Wg->Gear1);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glPopMatrix();

        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(3.1f, -2, 0);
        glRotatef(-2 * (float) Wg->Angle - 9, 0, 0, 1);
        glCallList(Wg->Gear2);
        glPopMatrix();

        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-3.1f, 4.2f, 0);
        glRotatef(-2 * (float) Wg->Angle - 25, 0, 0, 1);
        glCallList(Wg->Gear3);
        glPopMatrix();

        glPopMatrix();

        Togl_SwapBuffers(togl);

        return TCL_OK;
    }


    static int
    zap(ClientData clientData, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj *const *objv)
    {
        WHIRLYGIZMO *Wg;
        Togl   *togl;

        if (objc != 2) {
            Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 1, objv, "pathName");
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }

        if (Togl_GetToglFromObj(interp, objv[1], &togl) != TCL_OK) {
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }

        Wg = (WHIRLYGIZMO *) Togl_GetClientData(togl);
        free(Wg);

        return TCL_OK;
    }


    static int
    idle(ClientData clientData, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj *const *objv)
    {
        WHIRLYGIZMO *Wg;
        Togl   *togl;

        if (objc != 2) {
            Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 1, objv, "pathName");
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }

        if (Togl_GetToglFromObj(interp, objv[1], &togl) != TCL_OK) {
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }

        Wg = (WHIRLYGIZMO *) Togl_GetClientData(togl);
        Wg->Angle += 2;
        Togl_PostRedisplay(togl);

        return TCL_OK;
    }


    static int
    reshape(ClientData clientData, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc,
            Tcl_Obj *const *objv)
    {
        int     width, height;
        Togl   *togl;

        if (objc != 2) {
            Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 1, objv, "pathName");
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }

        if (Togl_GetToglFromObj(interp, objv[1], &togl) != TCL_OK) {
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }

        width = Togl_Width(togl);
        height = Togl_Height(togl);
        glViewport(0, 0, (GLint) width, (GLint) height);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        if (width > height) {
            GLfloat w = (GLfloat) width / (GLfloat) height;

            glFrustum(-w, w, -1, 1, 5, 60);
        } else {
            GLfloat h = (GLfloat) height / (GLfloat) width;

            glFrustum(-1, 1, -h, h, 5, 60);
        }

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glTranslatef(0, 0, -40);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        return TCL_OK;
    }


    static int
    init(ClientData clientData, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj *const *objv)
    {
        WHIRLYGIZMO *Wg;
        static GLfloat red[4] = { 0.8f, 0.1f, 0, 1 };
        static GLfloat green[4] = { 0, 0.8f, 0.2f, 1 };
        static GLfloat blue[4] = { 0.2f, 0.2f, 1, 1 };
        static GLfloat pos[4] = { 5, 5, 10, 0 };
        Togl   *togl;

        if (objc != 2) {
            Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 1, objv, "pathName");
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }

        if (Togl_GetToglFromObj(interp, objv[1], &togl) != TCL_OK) {
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }

        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, pos);
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        /* make the gears */
        Wg = (WHIRLYGIZMO *) malloc(sizeof (WHIRLYGIZMO));
        if (!Wg) {
            Tcl_SetResult(Togl_Interp(togl),
                    "\"Cannot allocate client data for widget\"", TCL_STATIC);
        }
        Wg->Gear1 = glGenLists(1);
        glNewList(Wg->Gear1, GL_COMPILE);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, red);
        gear(1, 4, 1, 20, 0.7f);
        glEndList();

        Wg->Gear2 = glGenLists(1);
        glNewList(Wg->Gear2, GL_COMPILE);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, green);
        gear(0.5f, 2, 2, 10, 0.7f);
        glEndList();

        Wg->Gear3 = glGenLists(1);
        glNewList(Wg->Gear3, GL_COMPILE);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, blue);
        gear(1.3f, 2, 0.5f, 10, 0.7f);
        glEndList();

        glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
        Wg->Height = Togl_Height(togl);
        Wg->Width = Togl_Width(togl);
        Wg->Angle = 0;
        Wg->Rotx = 0;
        Wg->Roty = 0;
        Wg->Rotz = 0;
        Togl_SetClientData(togl, (ClientData) Wg);

        return TCL_OK;
    }

    static int
    position(ClientData clientData, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc,
            Tcl_Obj *const *objv)
    {
        WHIRLYGIZMO *Wg;
        char    Result[100];
        Togl   *togl;

        if (objc != 2) {
            Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 1, objv, "pathName");
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }

        if (Togl_GetToglFromObj(interp, objv[1], &togl) != TCL_OK) {
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }

        Wg = (WHIRLYGIZMO *) Togl_GetClientData(togl);

        /* Let result string equal value */
        sprintf(Result, "%g %g", Wg->Roty, Wg->Rotx);

        Tcl_SetResult(interp, Result, TCL_VOLATILE);
        return TCL_OK;
    }

    static int
    rotate(ClientData clientData, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc,
            Tcl_Obj *const *objv)
    {
        WHIRLYGIZMO *Wg;
        Togl   *togl;

        if (objc != 4) {
            Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 1, objv, "pathName yrot xrot");
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }

        if (Togl_GetToglFromObj(interp, objv[1], &togl) != TCL_OK) {
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }

        Wg = (WHIRLYGIZMO *) Togl_GetClientData(togl);

        if (Tcl_GetDoubleFromObj(interp, objv[2], &Wg->Roty) != TCL_OK) {
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }
        if (Tcl_GetDoubleFromObj(interp, objv[3], &Wg->Rotx) != TCL_OK) {
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }
        Togl_PostRedisplay(togl);

        return TCL_OK;
    }

    EXTERN int
    Gears_Init(Tcl_Interp *interp)
    {
        /* 
         * Initialize Tcl and the Togl widget module.
         */
        if (Tcl_InitStubs(interp, "8.1", 0) == NULL
                || Togl_InitStubs(interp, "2.0", 0) == NULL) {
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }

        /* 
         * Specify the C callback functions for widget creation, display,
         * and reshape.
         */
        Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, "init", init, NULL, NULL);
        Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, "zap", zap, NULL, NULL);
        Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, "draw", draw, NULL, NULL);
        Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, "reshape", reshape, NULL, NULL);
        Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, "idle", idle, NULL, NULL);
        Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, "rotate", rotate, NULL, NULL);
        Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, "position", position, NULL, NULL);
        return TCL_OK;
    }
```

The corresponding .tcl File is

```
if { [file exists pkgIndex.tcl] } {
set auto_path [linsert $auto_path 0 ..]
}
# following load also loads Tk and Togl packages
load [file dirname [info script]]/togl20[info sharedlibextension]
load [file dirname [info script]]/gears[info sharedlibextension]

 # create ::gears namespace
namespace eval ::gears {
}

proc ::gears::setup {} {
  global startx starty xangle0 yangle0 xangle yangle RotCnt
  global vTime
  set RotCnt 1
  set xangle 0.0
  set yangle 0.0
  set vTime 100
  wm title . "Rotating Gear Widget Test"

  label .t -text "Click and drag to rotate image"
  pack .t -side top -padx 2 -pady 10
  frame .f
  pack .f -side top
  button .f.n1 -text "  Add " -command ::gears::AutoRot
  button .f.r1 -text "Remove" -command ::gears::DelRot
  button .f.b1 -text " Quit " -command exit 
  entry .f.t -width 4 -textvariable vTime
  pack .f.n1 .f.t .f.r1 .f.b1 -side left -anchor w -padx 5
  newRot .w0 10

}

proc ::gears::newRot {win {tick 10000} } {
  togl $win -width 200 -height 200 -rgba true -double true -depth true 
  -privatecmap false -time $tick -create init -destroy zap -display draw 
  -reshape reshape -timer idle
  bind $win <ButtonPress-1> {::gears::RotStart %x %y %W}
  bind $win <B1-Motion> {::gears::RotMove %x %y %W}
  pack $win -expand true -fill both
}

if { [info script] == $argv0 } {
::gears::setup
}
```

I absolutely don't have a clue, what I could try to do next, as with other Togl versions wglMakeCurrent fails with 2005 and I also cannot resolve this properly.